# Guzzle encodes body to Json, but I want form data

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm tyring to post something to `Googles oAuth server` to do some authentication. Google really wants this information in form data (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) but my [guzzle](/questions/tagged/guzzle) client seems to insist (as far as I can tell) on making the body JSON. I'm using Guzzle 4.*

I've changed my URL to a `PostCatcher.io url`, so I can see what comes out (because for the life of my I can't figure out how to see the actual raw HTTP request that guzzle spits out), and it looks like theres JSON coming out.

My code (I'm using a test url by now):

```
$client = new GuzzleClient();
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/" . "oauth2/v3/token";
$test_url = 'http://postcatcher.in/catchers/55602457b92ce203000032ae';

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', $test_url);
$request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); //should be redundant

$body = $request->getBody();
$body->setField('code', $code);
$body->setField('client_id', $this->client_id);
$body->setField('client_secret', $this->client_secret);
$body->setField('redirect_url', $this->redicrect_url);
$body->setField('grant_type', $this->grant_type);

try {
    $response = $client->send($request);

    $result = $response->getBody();

    return $result;

} catch (\Exception $exc) {
    return $exc->getCode() . ' ' . $exc->getMessage();
}
```

> The documentation says this should be enough. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I did upgrade to Guzzle 5.* tho I suspect that wasn't actually the solution.

I just neede to look at the response content. So in the exception clause of the call I added:

```
if ($exc->hasResponse()) {
   return $exc->getResponse()->json();
}
```

Which gave me a clear error message from Google. The error message was "Missing parameter: redirect_uri". And that's because I had written `url` instead of `uri`.

Fixed that, and now it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Using Guzzle 5.2 I've done the same thing with:

```
$request = $this->createRequest(
    $method,
    $uri,
    ['body' => $php_array_of_values ]
);

$response = $this->send($request);
```